# Put input in new div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add my input into new div.

My input:

```
<input id="id_bic" type="text" name="bic" />
```

Needed output:

```
<div class="input-append">
     <input id="id_bic" type="text" name="bic"/> <!-- this is my input -->
     <button type="submit" class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

I need to put my input field here (this code does not exist in my html yet):

```
<div class="input-append">
     <!-- here I need my input -->
     <button type="submit" class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What are you asking?

Comment: try this: var input = $("#id_bic"); $("#input-append").prepend(input);

Comment: please clarify that you know div id or you want to create new div and what you want to append in div.It can be easily achieved by using .append() method of jquery API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand from your question

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5uhxP/

First you move the inout inside DIV using wrap, and then you create button and insertAfter input..

```
$('input').wrap("<div class='input-append'>");
$("<button type='submit' class='add-on'>").insertAfter('#id_bic');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/sL2cx/2)</kbd>

```
$('div.input-append').prepend('<input id="id_bic" type="text" name="bic" />');
```

---

if input already in DOM

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/sL2cx/)</kbd>

```
$('div.input-append').prepend($('#id_bic'));
```

Comment: this could be a correct answer but the question is really too much unclear